# Объекты в коллайдере 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу разобраться как получить список объектов в коллайдере. Нюанс в том, что несколько объектов появляются одновременно и ОнТриггерИнтео регистрирует только один объект... ОнТриггерСтэй тоже как то не туда...

Comment: Вообщето коллайдер это компонент, который вешается на обьект. На один. Коллайдер не может висеть на нескольких GameObject-ах. Обдумай вопрос и переформулируй его. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Используй вместо коллайдера что-то из overlap (сфера, коробка), например
Можно создать массив и в него будут вноситься объекты нужного тебе типа

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за  участие, но всё оказалось намного проще. Кое что упустил в механике движка.

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision)
    {
        if (!goList.Contains(collision.gameObject))
        {
            goList.Add(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

OnTriggerStay2D каждый кадр кидает в collision все объекты внутри. Их просто надо было выловить по-одному... )

Answer (score 1):

Ваше решение тоже имеет право на жизнь, однако, не совсем оптимально. Вы ведь сами дошли уже до того, что методы коллайдера вызываются для каждого другого коллайдера.

Так почему бы вам тогда не добавлять в ваш лист объект при OnTriggerEnter2D и удалять при OnTriggerExit2D?

При это, если порядок вам не важен, вы можете использовать [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) вместо `List<T>`.  Это несортированный набор элементов, который не может содержать дубликаты. Условно, при `Add(collision.gameObject)` он почти ничего не сделает, если объект в нём уже есть.

В то время, как в вашей реализации проверка `goList.Contains(collision.gameObject)` - приводит к обходу листа с целью поиска этого объекта. Т.е. если у вас 10 объектов и вы хотите добавить новый, то лист сначала проверит все эти десять на соответствие вашему, потом вернёт false и только потом вы добавите новый элемент, либо найдёт его в третьем слоте и вернёт true. Т.е. вы получаете множество проверок на равенство каждый кадр, даже если новых объектов нет.

Я бы предложил вот такой вариант:

```
HashSet<GameObject> _objInCollider = new HashSet<GameObject>();

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    _objInCollider.Add(collider.gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    _objInCollider.Remove(collider.gameObject);
}
```

Однако, из-за того, что `HashSet<T>` список не сортированный к его элементам нельзя обращаться через индекс, как к листу, а нужно работать со всем множеством через Enumerator, например, используя цикл `foreach`:

```
void Do()
{
    foreach(var item in _objInCollider)
    {
        //Сделать что-то с item
    }
}
```

Comment: Совет дельный. OnTriggerEnter2D отрабатывает исправно. А вот с выходом проблемка. Плюс элементы будут покидать триггер как сменой позиции, так и через Destroy. Не получается отследить этот момент :/

Comment: @IncDD, Смена позиции будет работать нормально, а вот при выключении/уничтожении объекта - да, будет косяк. Однако, если выключать коллайдер, а не объект, то выход сработает. Можете перенести уничтожение объекта в сам объект) и прежде чем вызвать Destroy - выключайте коллайдер) можете вместо использования OnExit сделать в объекте событие об уничтожении и подписываться на него из "слушателя", а перед удалением вызывать событие и удалять этот объект из списка.

Comment: Оказывается, OnExit уничтожение тоже норм обрабатывает...

Comment: @IncDD, проверял на выключении) видимо, при уничтожении деактивируется коллайдер и соответственно срабатывает выход.